# Existing JUnit Class not found exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am trying to run a test from XSDGeneratorTest.java. But I get the following exception:

```
Class not found com.level3.pcat.xsd.XSDGeneratorTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.level3.pcat.xsd.XSDGeneratorTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I tried to claen and build the project many a times but still same error!
I tried all the options from [JUNIT Test class in Eclipse - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716308/junit-test-class-in-eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexception), but none worked for me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639018/why-is-my-test-not-running

Comment: I resolved the issue by moving Maven Dependencies above JRE System Library and then executing mvn clean test. Somehow just moving Maven Dependencies above JRE System Library didnt work for me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381068/

Answer (score 0):

If that happens when you moved your project from one IDE/OS to another, just try to remove the JUnit3 library and add it again. Sometimes that fails when you bring your proyect from outside. I was stuck getting the same error until I did that.